# Recurrent output of printf() to stdout each time fork() is invoked allthough printf() is invoked prior to fork(). And why does '\n' fixes this?

Tags: ubuntu, c, stdout, fork

While I was playing around with `fork()` I noticed a rather strange behavior but I couldn't figure out myself why this happens.

In the example below, each time `fork()` is invoked the output from the `printf()` invocation prior to that is printed out to stdout. The value of `test` in the output shows that `printf()` does not really get executed again, otherwise this would increase `test` each time.

Even stranger - or maybe key to the solution - is the fact that this behavior doesn't occur when I add `\n` to the end of the format string of printf().

Does anybody know why this happens?
Maybe it is related to the stdout buffer? I'm not really familiar with this stuff.

Or am I doing something horribly wrong??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(char* args) {
    pid_t pid;
    int wstatus;
    int test = 0;

    printf("\n[%d] parent start | test = %d ", getpid(), test++);

    // This works fine
    //printf("\n[%d] parent start | test = %d \n", getpid(), test++);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
            //printf("\n[%d] Child spawned ", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        //printf("\n[%d] Printing with fork() commented out works fine", getpid());
    }

    while(wait(&wstatus) > 0);

    printf("\n[%d] parent end\n\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[342470] parent start | test = 0 [342470] parent start | test = 0 [342470] parent start | test = 0 [342470] parent start | test = 0 [342470] parent start | test = 0 [342470] parent start | test = 0 
[342470] parent end
```

In case it's of any use

```
$ uname -a
Linux Aspire 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` has written text to the *stdout* buffer, which is finally written in each branch of the fork via the `exit` call.